# Developing on linux, root or user?

Tags: linux

I set-up a linode account, installed arch linux and am happily using it as a web development environment and web server for my apps.

My question is: I'm doing everything as root, is that OK or should I create a user profile and use that for development?

Comment: if something is possible to do without root you should never do it as root !

Answer (score 1):

Create a user account. It's easy to mess up as root user.

Answer (score 1):

Create a user and become the superuser via `sudo` for limited tasks.

One of the greatest benefits is having an audit trail so you and your colleagues can know what system changes each other are making.